# How to fix 'TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion' in solidity?

Tags: solidity

error!

```
TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from uint8[9] memory to uint8[256] memory requested.
   --> contracts/Avatar/DistrictPower.sol:208:20:
    |
208 |         setStock(1,[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]);
    |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

code!

```
constructor() {
        setStock(1,[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]);
        setStock(2,[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]);
        setStock(3,[21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30],[21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]);
    }

function setStock(
        uint256 ledgerType,
        uint8[] calldata typeDays,
        uint16[] calldata stock
    ) internal {
        require(ledgerType > 0, "Invalid ledger type");
        require(ledgerType < 6, "Invalid ledger type");
        require(msg.sender == tempAdmin, "Only admin");
        require(stock.length > 0, "Invalid stock array");
        require(typeDays.length == stock.length, "Invalid params");

        _setStock(ledgerType, typeDays, stock);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the error is by defining/initializing the array.
I don't know if is the most efficient way, et I would try:

```
uint8[] firstArray = new uint8[9]
firstarray[0] = 2
firstarray[1] = 3
...
...
firstarray[8] = 10
setStock(1,firstArray,[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]);
```

and the same for the others.
hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your help！I found a solution.

Comment: great, how was it?, so others can also understand in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I encapsulated a method

```
(uint8[] memory typeDays1,uint16[] memory stock1) = generateTypeDaysAndStock(2, 10);
        setStock(1, typeDays1, stock1);

function generateTypeDaysAndStock(uint8 start, uint8 end) internal pure returns (uint8[] memory, uint16[] memory) {
        require(start < end, "Invalid range");

        uint8 length = end - start + 1;
        uint8[] memory typeDays = new uint8[](length);
        uint16[] memory stock = new uint16[](length);

        for (uint8 i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            typeDays[i-start] = i;
            stock[i-start] = i;
        }

        return (typeDays, stock);
    }
```